# Kibana gauge with dynamic maximum value

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I have a data coming from logstash that shows how much space is used on a table in a database and maximum allocated capacity for a table. I want to create in Kibana gauges for every table that show how much space is currently occupied.

The problem is that maximum available space sometimes changes so the limit for a gauge has to be set as a variable and I can't figure out how to do this. I also don't know how to show only data from current day on a dashboard for a time range. Data coming from logstash looks like that:

```
time     | table_name | used_gb | max_gb
---------+------------+---------+--------
25.04.18 | table_1    | 1.2     | 10.4
25.04.18 | table_2    | 4.6     | 5.0
26.04.18 | table_1    | 1.4     | 14.6
26.04.18 | table_2    | 4.9     | 5.0
```

I want my gauge for every table to look something like that:

[image: gauge]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved using Time Series Visual Builder.

Choose `Gauge`, then `Panel options`, you can specify `1` as your max value. Then in your gauge data settings you can compute the dynamic ratio per table. Here's a screenshot of a similar setup:
[image: Example configuration]

In older versions of Kibana instead of Bucket Script you should use Calculation Aggregation.

Reference:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/gauge-with-dynamic-maximum-value/130634/2